# phonecallTask not working in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

`PhoneCallTask` is not working in Windows Phone 8.

I have followed [this blog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394025%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAWmInoBUHg), but the code is not working on my windows phone 8.

The code is:

```
PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();       
phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = "9021332536";
phoneCallTask.DisplayName = "Rehan";
phoneCallTask.Show();
```

Comment: Can you see phoneDialer permissions in app manifest file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to add a PhoneCallTask:

```
 PhoneCallTask callTask = new PhoneCallTask();
 callTask.PhoneNumber = "999999";
 callTask.DisplayName = "Support";
 callTask.Show();
```

Remember to enable ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER in your WMAppManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try to use :

```
new PhoneCallTask
{
     DisplayName = "My name", PhoneNumber = "My phone number"
}.Show();
```

and not forget to enable "ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER" in your WMAppManifest.xml (expand properties).